# Website won't scroll down on certain browsers

Tags: html, css, wordpress, scroll

For some reason a website we've just put live won't scroll in certain browsers. It's hard to replicate but I've seen someone on a Mac using Chrome being unable to scroll down the page.

Can anyone help? I'm thinking it might be a z-indexing issue but can't pin it down. I have noticed that the menu bar sometimes goes over the top of the scroll bar.

Comment: im sorry for not having an answer but i can confirm it doesn't scroll for me on Chrome, but Safari is completely fine.

what is worth noting, however, is that if I scroll on Chrome before the video element loads then I make progress down the page, but once fully loaded scrolling stops.

Comment: As a side note, I can't use the mouse's scroll wheel, but using the scroll bar does scroll the page.

Comment: Holy stylesheets 'n scripts batman! Make sure it's not one of the 50 scripts you're loading that's disabling scroll. How many plugins did it take to build the puppy?

Comment: @Ross Coulbeck I'm on a Mac, using Chrome, and I can't scroll down the page. However, I found out the scroll bar is behind the header on the top of the page. That might be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "height: auto":

```
body, html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: auto;
}
```

Edit: You should really compress your images and scripts and.. everything. Your site is really badly optimized: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Frumpuspr.com%2F

Comment: I was a little worried **PageSpeed Insights** was going to break testing that site, 8/100 and 14/100 - _ouch!_.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. Don't worry, this is a preliminary release, it will be optimised :)

Comment: Oh thank goodness! Music to my weary ears! I will be testing it again in the coming months, :P.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have at least one scroll-related JavaScript library loading inside the theme assets, too.  If your issue isn't already resolved, might be worth looking into cross-browser compatibility.